# Siebel - Issue With Activity Templates

Tags: siebel

I am fairly new to Siebel. There is an issue in which -

A Template is created in the Activity Plan List Applet and certain Activities are added in the Activity Plan Action Applet.
But i dont find those activities available in the LN Account Activity List Applet.(This Applet is available in the Account Summary Tab of the Accounts Screen)

Business Components and associated Applets:

```
1.Activity Plan           - Activity Plan List Applet
2.Activity Plan Action    - Activity Plan Action Applet
3.LN Action               - LN Account Activity List Applet
```

I chechked the link between the business components:

Links:

```
Account/LN Action        -  Source Field(Id), Dest Field(Primary Coverage Company Id)
Account/Activity Plan    -  Source Field(Id), Dest Field(Account Id)
```

I need to auto-populate the Field - Primary Coverage Company Id.

How do i proceed with the auto-population?

Comment: What is your Siebel version? Seems that `LN Account Activity List Applet` and underlying BC are either custom object, or belong to some vertical application. I don't have it in vanilla repository.

Comment: Siebel eMedia 8.1.Yes LN Account Activity List Applet and LN Action are custom objects.